# Upgrade/downgrade OS without custom recovery and root

Tags: stock-android

My smartphone model is Lenovo A7000a. Let's say I want to install Lollipop in it. More specifically, I already have Lollipop installed, but I want to reinstall Lollipop. Or say, I want to install downgraded versions like Jellibean, etc. Now my phone is rooted, Xposed installed, custom recovery installed.

Now, I don't want to install custom recovery. I want to know how the service centers install OS without custom recovery and even root.

Can anyone please tell me this process? How service centers installed any released OS in phone with only stock recovery and without root?

Comment: I believe you only need to unlock the bootloader. For Google Nexus (and I believe Pixel) products, they can just flash the stock ROM without needing to flash custom recovery. Root is definitely not needed (it even prevents the flashing in Nexus)

Comment: They simply flash a firmware (stock) which comes with a stock recovery and has no root.